# GoDaddy domain on GCP is not secured

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, devops

I have a domain (let's assume it's domainName.com) on GoDaddy with redirection to the same domain but with a **https://www.**domainName.com prefix. At the same time in my GCP App Engine I added custom domains: domainName.com (with record types: A, AAAA) and [www.domainName.com](http://www.domainName.com) (record type: CNAME).

Then when entering the website using google chrome, I can see that domains https:// and https://www are considered as secured, but standard websites: domainName.com and [www.domainName.com](http://www.domainName.com) are not. Is there a quick fix for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL `http://www.dommainName.com` is not secure (by design). That URL uses the protocol `http` and not `https`.

The URL `https://www.dommainName.com` is secure (by design). That URL uses the protocol `https` and not `http`.

Today, most websites automatically manage users that arrive using the `http` protocol and redirect them to use the `https` protocol. This uses HTTP Redirects (3xx).

Google App Engine Standard (not Flexible) supports automatically redirecting users to use `https`. Modify the application's `app.yaml` to use `secure: always`.

Example:

```
handlers:
- url: /youraccount/.*
  script: accounts.app
  login: required
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

Read this document on app.yaml for more details:

[app.yaml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref)